# getting an error after trying to test a query in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

getting this error:

```
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "memcache"
```

while im trying to do this query:

```
model = Model.get_by_id(key)
```

im trying to test some querys but im not using testbed or anything im doing it throught the testing server because it envolves blobstorage and more stuff

do anyone have an idea of what is happening?

Comment: You'll need to give more information about how you're running this test. It shouldn't surprise you though that if you are not using the testbed you will get errors like this.

Comment: i made a script to connect to the development test with the library requests then i send an image and i get a url for uploading it and add to a model this upload.key() after this i wanna query this models to get the one that has an image like i showed in the question and this problem happens, i cant do this with testbed because its not posible(as far as know) to upload something into blobstore with testbed

Comment: Since you're using a custom testbed, I'd say we need more info on THAT if you want to be able to get help here. It's hard, since it's your own script that connects to the dev server. What I do know is that if your get_by_id is made on ndb, you COULD disable memcache at the ndb level.